# Getting an Environment Variable in Terraform configuration?

Tags: configuration, terraform

I have two environment variables. One is `TF_VAR_UN` and another is `TF_VAR_PW`. Then I have a terraform file that looks like this.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
    name = "marcellus-wallace"
    zone = "us-central1-a"
    initial_node_count = 3

    master_auth {
        username = ${env.TF_VAR_UN}
        password = ${env.TF_VAR_PW}
    }

    node_config {
        oauth_scopes = [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
        ]
    }
}
```

The two values I'd like to replace with the environment variables `TF_VAR_UN` and `TF_VAR_PW` are the values username and password. I tried what is shown above, with no success, and I've toyed around with a few other things but always get syntax issues.

Comment: Super tut at https://build5nines.com/use-terraform-input-variables-to-parameterize-infrastructure-deployments/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I would try something more like this, which seems closer to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html).

```
variable "UN" {
  type = string
}

variable "PW" {
  type = string
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name = "marcellus-wallace"
  zone = "us-central1-a"
  initial_node_count = 3

  master_auth {
    username = var.UN
    password = var.PW
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
    ]
  }
}
```

With the CLI command being the below.

```
TF_VAR_UN=foo TF_VAR_PW=bar terraform apply
```

Comment: The trailing `terraform apply` part confused me about TF_VARS`
You can also just `export TF_VAR_your_var` or have in a dot file like `.profile`

Comment: that's normal syntax to have your shell set environment variables for a single command

Comment: ${var.UN} --> "${var.UN}"
${var.PW} --> "${var.PW}"

Comment: @Jeremy Curious, what's the problem?

Answer (score 8):

The use of interpolation syntax throws warning with terraform `v0.12.18`. Now you don't need to use the interpolation syntax. You can just reference it as `var.hello`.

**Caution :** 
One important thing to understand from a language standpoint is that, you cannot declare variables using environment variables. You can only assign values for declared variables in the script using environment varibles. For example, let's say you have the following .tf script

`variable "hello" {
   type=string
}`

Now if the environment has a variable TF_VAR_hello="foobar", during runtime the variable hello will have the value "foobar". If you assign the variable without the declaration of the variable there will not be any effect.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following to get this working.

1. Declare the variable in terraform configuration that you want to use as environment Variable.

```
variable "db_password" { type= string }
```

2. In the resource section where you want to use this variable change it as

```
"db_password":"${var.db_password}"
```

3. Export the environment variable.

```
export TF_VAR_db_password="##password##"
```

4. `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`null_resource`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) to execute a terminal command (read an environment variable), redirect output to a file, then read the file content:

```hcl
resource "null_resource" "read_environment_var_value_via_cli" {
  triggers = { always_run = "${timestamp()}" }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $TF_VAR_UN > TF_VAR_UN.txt" # add gitignore
  }
}

data "local_file" "temp_file" {
  depends_on    = [ null_resource.read_environment_var_value_via_cli]
  filename      = "${path.module}/TF_VAR_UN.txt" 
}

# use value as desired
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
    master_auth {
        username = data.local_file.temp_file.content # value of $TF_VAR_UN
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the providers use:

> DefaultFunc: schema.EnvDefaultFunc("

- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-infoblox/blob/master/infoblox/provider.go
- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-openstack/blob/master/openstack/provider.go
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can replace the variables in the file itself using the `envsubst` utility in bash:

```
$ envsubst < main.tf > main.tf
```

Or using an intermediate file with variables and the final config on the output:

```
$ envsubst < main.txt > main.tf
```

**! Variables for `envsubst` must be declared using `export`**:

```
$ export MYVAR=1729
```

The variables in the source file must be of the form: `$VARIABLE` or `${VARIABLE}`.

Answer (score -2):

in order to use a variable it needs to be wrapped with ""
for example:

> username = "${var.UN}"

Comment: The original poster was referring to environment variables, not Terraform variables. Therefore your answer is not sufficient.

Comment: this syntax is no longer required for HCL 2. In HCL 2, you can omit the quotation marks and just use `var.<variable_name>`